# Constructing embedded families of curves with general moduli

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, algebraic-curves, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes, brill-noether

Is there a known way to construct flat families of smooth curves $\mathcal{C}/\mathcal{B}$ which are fiberwise embedded in a family of projective varieties $\mathcal{X}/\mathcal{B}$ and which have general moduli (i.e., the forgetful map $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{M}_g$ which discards the embedding and takes every curve to its isomorphism type is dominant)?

When we take all fibers of $\mathcal{X}$ to be projective spaces this can be done by Brill-Noether theory. I'm looking for alternative constructions which either don't use Brill-Noether, or consider different target spaces.

Comment: For every smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension at least $3$ that is separably rationally connected, for every $g\geq 0$, for every $r\geq 0$, for all sufficiently positive curve classes $\beta$, for the stack $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta)^o$ parameterizing embeddings of $r$-pointed, genus $g$ curves with class $\beta$, for the associated morphism $(\text{ev},\Phi):\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(X,\beta) \to (X^r)\times \mathcal{M}_{g,r}$, the open subset of the domain where the morphism is smooth is nonempty . . .

Comment: . . . Thus, for any $Y$ that contains such an $X$, again $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(Y,\beta)\to \mathcal{M}_{g,r}$ is surjective for infinitely many $\beta$, e.g., for the classes of curves in $X$.  Thus, fix an integer $d$, and consider a $d$-fold $Y$ containing no rationally connected subvariety.  Thus $Y$ contains no uniruled $Z$.  For all $g$ with $3g-3>d$, by Bend-and-Break, if there exists a family of curves in $Z$ dominating $\mathcal{M}_g$ and such that a general point of $Z$ is contained in one of these curves, then $Z$ is uniruled.  Thus, a general curve of genus $g$ does not embed in $Y$.

Comment: @Jason: thanks! If I understand your answer correctly, you're saying that a necessary and sufficient condition for the problem to be meaningful with a constant target space $X$ is to have it contain a rationally connected subvariety? ... is the answer different if I want to let $X$ be a flat family over the base?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.  What is the "base" in your question?

Comment: The base $B$ parametrizes both the family of algebraic curves, and the family of varieties they can be embedded in. The map $B \to M_g$ which sends each curve to its isomorphism type should be surjective.

Comment: About the dependence on the base parameter: Really, I should only demand the family of curves and varieties vary smoothly with the base parameter (along with a certain global condition [non-degenerate 2-form on the total space which restricts to a symplectic form on the fibers] that forces them to be locally Hamiltonian fibrations) but for now, I'm curious what can be said in the context of algebraic/analytic geometry.

Comment: @JasonStarr Also (maybe stupid question), why is it true that a general curve in $\mathcal{M}_{g,r}(Y,\beta)$ is embedded? I know that symplectically, when $\dim_\mathbb{C}(X) \geq 3$ simple J-holomorphic curves are of index 0 are generically embedded, but why is it obvious that among your classes $\beta$ there is one which is not represented only by multiple covers?

Comment: Such classes obviously exist (e.g. the multiple of any exceptional fiber in a blowup). In other words: I believe a generic simple curve is embedded when the dimension of the target is more then 6. Why is the set of simple curves not empty for these $\beta$? (I assume you will say by factorization theorem like McDuff-Salamon, there are primitive classes in homology etc. But why is it obvious that such a primitive class would be "sufficiently positive")?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55637/discussion-between-nati-and-jason-starr).